# How to do IP Canonicalization in .htaccess? for wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, ip, ip-address, canonicalization

IP canonicalization is the process of making sure that all versions of your website that can be accessed using an IP address are redirected to the domain name version of the site. This helps to improve the user experience and ensure that search engines are able to crawl and index your site properly.

Answer (score 0):

The IP canonicalization applied in cases that IP address and domain name are NOT resolving to the same endpoint which is your website/webapp. Today is hard to face this issue. First of all you have to check if you have problem with resolving. If you spot any issue you can add these lines to your .htaccess file or the vhost in nginx:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where the `XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX` is your IP && `http://www.yourdomain.com/$1` with your domain name.

Remember, use this with caution and only if you have problem with resolving.